# R - terra::distance() equivalent of raster::gridDistance(..., origin = x, omit = y)

Tags: r, distance, raster, spatial, terra

**UPDATE** - this question relates to `terra 1.4-1`, and is now obsolete with `terra 1.5-12` (or earlier?).

---

I am looking for the `terra` equivalent of `raster::gridDistance(..., origin = my_origin, omit = my_omit)`.

I found what looks to be an old webpage on `terra::gridDistance`, from `terra v0.2-8` [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/terra/versions/0.2-8/topics/gridDistance), but from what I can gather `terra::distance` is the current replacement for `raster::gridDistance` ([list of `terra's` replacement functions here](https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/terra-package.html)).

However, I don't know to implement `omit = my_omit` (or equivalent) in `terra::distance`. From the [documentation page](https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/distance.html) it looks like any non-NA is deemed the `origin`, but there is no reference to `omit`, or the option to change the `origin` to a specific value (unlike the `raster::gridDistance` example below).

This is the example from `raster::gridDistance`:

```
library(raster)

# world lon/lat raster
r <- raster(ncol=10,nrow=10, vals=1)
r[48] <- 2     # this will be the origin
r[66:68] <- 3  # this will be the area that can't be traversed
plot(r)

d <- gridDistance(r,origin=2,omit=3) 
plot(d)
```

[image]

Can anyone reproduce this example using `terra::distance`?

I can do what I need to do using `raster`, but I'm still learning how to handle spatial raster data properly and am making an effort to learn the new `terra` package.

Comment: Hi @hugh-allan, my comment may be too late, but I want to let you know that your code works perfectly well using the `terra::gridDistance()` function of the `terra v.1.5.12` library. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks very much, it is never too late for an answer! I was originally using `terra v1.4-1`, which explains why the function seemed to be 'missing'. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Glad that I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @lovalery for pointing this out in the comments.

In the original question I was using `terra 1.4-1`. As of January 2022, `terra 1.5-12` has been released (Jan 13th 2022), and it now includes a `terra::gridDistance()` function which is very similar to the `raster::gridDistance()` function.

For the sake of completeness, this is the example from `?terra::gridDistance`:

```
#world lon/lat raster
r <- rast(ncol=10,nrow=10, vals=1)
r[48] <- 2
r[66:68] <- 3
d <- gridDistance(r,origin=2,omit=3) 
plot(d)

#UTM small area
crs(r) <- "+proj=utm +zone=15 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
d <- gridDistance(r,origin=2,omit=3) 
plot(d)
```

[image]