# raster::gridDistance() fails on medium to large raster files

Tags: r, distance, raster, spatial, terra

I have some moderate sized raster files (max size ~190 MB) that I would like to calculate grid distances for using `raster::gridDistance()`

I'm finding that the operation is slow and/or R crashes for the largest of my files. **Please note:** I'm not seeking memory management advice (e.g. maxing out `memory.limit()`, breaking into smaller rasters or pursuing parallel processing methods) as these are sidestepping my issue. If grid distances should not be attempted for 190+ MB size files, then I will just break the job into more manageable pieces.

The [raster::gridDistance() documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/gridDistance.html) mentions that I can try to solve "errors in the case of complex objects spread over different chunks... by varying the chunk size, see function `setOptions()`" and that "Additional distance measures and options (directions, cost-distance) are available in the `{gdistance}` package", but I have been hesitant to pursue these without better understanding the limitations/considerations.

Thanks to this question [R - terra::distance() equivalent of raster::gridDistance(..., origin = x, omit = y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69024832/r-terradistance-equivalent-of-rastergriddistance-origin-x-omit) I understand that there is an alternative method using `terra::gridDistance()`, but I am not able to discern if the operation is any more efficient or suitable for my needs than `raster::gridDistance()`

I haven't posted a reprex or session info as my question is really as follows:

1. Is `terra::gridDistance()` (or some other alternative like those offered by `{gdistance}`) really a more efficient (faster) or customizable way for calculating a grid distance using moderate-large raster files?
2. If not, what are considerations for changing how the grid distance is calculated (varying chunk size or other means) using `raster::gridDistance()` and `setOptions()`?

If there is interest, I can reformat my question so that it better fits guidelines with a reprex etc. Also, I am posting the question here rather than [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) because the original linked question was posted here.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that there is an alternative method using terra::gridDistance(), but I am not able to discern if the operation is any more efficient or suitable for my needs

Well, did you try it? That could have been more efficient than writing a long question.

The help file does not mention the limitations that `raster::gridDistance` has, so you should be good to go. But note that the method was renamed to `terra::gridDist()`

The "terra" package is the replacement for "raster" package; so "terra" is the best starting point more generally, I think.

Comment: Thank you @robert-hijmans for taking the time to comment and for your excellent work on the packages. The reason I started with `raster::gridDistance()` is because I have been trying to replicate some work that makes extensive use of it. I wanted to ask here before wading too deeply into changing the script without better understanding the consequences. I will use `terra::gridDist()` as you have suggested and report any interesting findings back here.